# Return results grouped horizontaly in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

This is a MS Access question

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Stuff        Type
-----        -----
Car          Chevy
Car          Honda
Pet          Cat
Electronic   TV
Electronic   Phone
Electronic   Computer
```

Would like it to look like this:

```
Stuff    Type1   Type2   Type3
------     ----    -----   -----
Car       Chevy   Honda
Pet         Cat
Electronic  TV     Phone   Computer
```

Just need to find the first 3 returned item of a group

Comment: Easy method.  Assign the Type1 to Type 3 headers for each unique instance of Type, then run a pivot against those headers.

Comment: Harder method.  Two passes.  First is to create a table with the unique "Stuff" column.  Second, use  nested loops to run through each stuff/type combo, and while it's matching stuff, you write to the type columns (create a new "Type" column if one doesn't exist).  Loop through each Stuff until you reach your EOF.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have an id field in the table, since you say you want the first three items returned only:

```
SELECT MyThings.Stuff, 
   Max(IIf([SRT]=1,[Type],Null)) AS Type1, 
   Max(IIf([SRT]=2,[Type],Null)) AS Type2, 
   Max(IIf([SRT]=3,[Type],Null)) AS Type3
FROM (SELECT MyTable.id, MyTable.Stuff, MyTable.Type, 
     (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM MyTable T WHERE T.Stuff = MyTable.Stuff AND
        T.id <= MyTable.id) AS SRT
      FROM MyTable) AS MyThings
WHERE (((MyThings.SRT)<=3))
GROUP BY MyThings.Stuff
ORDER BY Min(MyThings.id)
```

As long as the number of types is predefined this method should work for you.